# How to setup widget size correctly?

Tags: android, android-widget

I need to make a widget with size 4x1 cells. Here is my code:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:minHeight="40dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:configure="ru.bartwell.myapp.WidgetActivity" />
```

I test it on two virtual devices in Genymotion:

1. Google Nexus 7, 800x1280, Android 4.4.4
2. Samsung Galaxy S5, 1080x1920, Android 4.4.4

And I get different results:

When android:minWidth="250dp" and android:minHeight="40dip" (new formula):

1. Google Nexus 7 - 3x1
2. Samsung Galaxy S5 - 4x1

When android:minWidth="292dp" and android:minHeight="70dip" (old formula):

1. Google Nexus 7 - 4x1
2. Samsung Galaxy S5 - 4x2

As I see widget size depends of screen resolution. But I just need to get 4x1 widget's size on all devices. How to correctly setup widget size?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you generate a number of widgets with different sizes as not all people understand the concept of resizing.